# Include a class from a different directory in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am quite new to C#, but I encounter a problem about how to include a class from a different directory. Specifically, the files are stored like:

```
---
 |--- main.cs (class main{}, containing Main(){})
 |---
    |--- myClass.cs (class myClass{})
```

In `./main.cs`, I have the `Main()` function included in a class called `main`, and it needs to use a class called `myClass` stored in `./subdir/myClass.cs`. However, I don't know how to include the `./subdir/myClass.cs` in `main.cs`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats the namespace of `myClass`? You can see it at the start of the file

Comment: access them through `namespace`

Comment: You are using visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I am using vs2013, and myClass and main are in the same namespace.

Comment: It seems the directory `./subdir` must be explicitly created in VS2013. If not, VS will not see the files within it. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the solution explorer -> show all file -> navigate to the directory -> Include In Project.

[image]